# uber API | Проблема с авторизацией для получения токена

Tags: php, api, curl

У меня есть данный код

```
 $client_id = 'xxxxxxxx';
    $redirect_uri = 'https://mydomen.app/';
    $grand_type = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=$client_id&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'cache-control: no-cache',
        )
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type='.$grand_type.'&username=tested@gmail.com&password=password');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36');

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($result);
```

Но мне постоянно возвращает (и это нормально, если я правильно понимаю документацию)

[image: User authorizes your app]

Я следую следующим шагам , как описано здесь
https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/user-access-token

В документации написано что меня перенаправит на 302, а затем на `redirect_uri`
но как мне это получить с CURL?

Также я понимаю, что мне нужно будет ввести пароль и логин, я отправляю POSt данные, но правильно ли. Никак не могу получить URL с `code`

Comment: Раз в документации сказано что на этот адрес нужен GET запрос - вот его и делайте. А для проверки кода используйте curl_getinfo($result, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)

Comment: А почему вы делаете curl'ом это? Насколько я понимаю, человек должен перейти по этому урлу, чтобы авторизоваться там и потом перейти обратно по $redirect_uri

Comment: Так как мне правильно поступить? Я ничего не могу понять, как правильно сделать.